# XServer won't start on cluster

Tags: ssh, centos-7, x-server

I am trying to start a XServer in order to perform graphical renderings on the cluster GPU with Paraview. Since the cluster is usally driven by a task scheduler, the xserver is usually not running. For visualizations I need to start a Xserver in combination with the Paraview server.

If I try to start the XServer manually with

```
xinit
```

I recieve the following error message:

```
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) PAM authentication failed, cannot start X server.
Perhaps you do not have console ownership?
(EE) 
(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
 at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE)
```

I tried to use `xclock` from `ssh -X` and that works. If I try `glxinfo` then it won't work.

I am logging in from a remote machine via ssh. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. In my case I solved by changing the file `/etc/pam.d/xserver`.

Change the line `auth required pam_console.so` to `auth sufficient pam_permit.so`